# AoT compilation module.id error Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I want to the AoT compilation for my angular 2 project.

I have separated my application into `js` directory where all my generated `.js` files are and an `app` directory where I keep my `.ts`, `.html` and `.css` files together.

For the AoT compilation I use the `tsconfig.aot.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "js",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "types": [
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "app/main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "js",
    "app"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

and the script: `"ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && npm run copy \"app/*\" \"compiled\" "`

Currently I have my com,ponents like this:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'fs-mainbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/mainbar/mainbar.component.html'
 })
export class MainbarComponent {
```

But when I try to run the script it gives me this error:

```
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 ngc C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp
> ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && npm run copy "app/*" "compiled"

Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp/app/mainbar/app/mainbar/mainbar.component.html
    at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:291:19)
    at CompilerHost.loadResource (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:230:85)
    at Object.get (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:26374:111)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13753:47)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13799:25)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13771:48)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18074:79)
    at C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18250:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd
.js:18249:45)
Compilation failed
```

So ok I should use `module.id`, but because I have seprated my app into `js` and `app` folders I have to use it like this:

```
 @Component({
     moduleId: module.id.replace("/js/", "/app/"),
     selector: 'escl-mainbar',
     templateUrl: './mainbar.component.html'
 })
export class MainbarComponent {
```

This how ever gives me this error:

```
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 ngc C:\dev_escal\project\escal\ui\src\main\webapp
> ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && npm run copy "app/*" "compiled"

Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'module', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a re
ference to an exported function, resolving symbol MainbarComponent in C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp/app/mainbar/mainbar.component.ts, resolving symbol
 MainbarComponent in C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp/app/mainbar/mainbar.component.ts
```

So I'm pretty much stuck from here on. How can I fix this? Any help is welcomed :)

issue on github:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 export function moduleId() {
     return module.id.replace("/js/", "/app/");
 }

 @Component({
     moduleId: moduleId(),
     selector: 'escl-mainbar',
     templateUrl: './mainbar.component.html'
 })
export class MainbarComponent { }
```

Similar issue: [Angular2 AoT Compiler Errors](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262)

For more information about AOT compilation, and its advantages over JIT compilation visit: [Ahead-of-time (AOT) vs Just-in-time (JIT)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)

Comment: Hmm the example you gave doesn't really work, it still gives me the same error :(

Comment: You still see the same issue: 'Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'module...' ? And from the same file?

Comment: I've put the code for `moduleId` in a separate file like: 
`export function moduleId(moduleId: any) {
     return moduleId.replace("/js/", "/app/");
 }`

and use it like:

`moduleId: moduleId(module.id),`

in my module. This gives me the error:

Comment: `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'module', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a re
ference to an exported function, resolving symbol moduleId in C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp/app/module.resolutor.ts, resolving symbol MainbarComponent
 in C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp/app/mainbar/mainbar.component.ts, resolving symbol MainbarComponent in C:/dev_escal/project/escal/ui/src/main/webapp
/app/mainbar/mainbar.component.ts`

Comment: I'm using `@angular/compiler-cli` version `2.4.6` and typescript version `2.0.10`, But don't think that affects it somehow.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working for you. Referencing exported function fixes the problem in most cases. After all, the error description itself is pointing to that solution.

Comment: don't know either. I also added `<script>window.module = 'aot';</script>` like they say in the tutorial, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Just submited this as an issue on github, maybe they can tell